# iTunes Connect Submit for Review Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have used Xcode 5.1 to upload my build to iTunes connect successfully. When I go to the "prerelease" page at iTunes connect, I see my build showing up (although it says **inactive**). When I go to the "Versions" page I see a button that reads:

> "Click + to add a build before you submit your app"

I clicked it and selected the build that I just uploaded. However, after I clicked on "Submit for Review" the page said:

> "You must submit your builds using Xcode 5.1.1 or later, or
>   Application Loader 2.9.1 or later. After you’ve submitted a build,
>   select it in the Builds section below."

I have no idea what is going on.

I enabled TestFlight Beta Testing for the build and added two users. But the error keeps showing up.

How to work around this error?

Comment: You can't use Xcode beta versions to submit applications. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I think when it is in the prerelease we have to wait for it to finish processing before we may choose it as a build.  Seems slower than how they used to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that iTunes Connect does not like **inactive** builds. I solved the problem following the answer from nupac by doing the following:

1. In xcode I changed the build version, not the app version, so I could submit the app once again
2. Generated the Archive
3. Validate the archive before submitting
4. Submit archive
5. While the build was still "Processing", I went back to my apps new version page on iTunes Connect.
6. Choose the new build and submit for review.

Cheers

Comment: may help someone .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26144339/294884