# New iTunes connect interface -- should it IMMEDIATELY be seen on "Prerelease"?

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect, xcode6

Regarding the insane changes to itunesconnect.

When you successfully upload a build from Xcode,

[image]

It seems you have to wait until it appears here..fair enough.

[image]

BUT there is confusing information about the **prerelease** section.

[image]

## Should it IMMEDIATELY APPEAR on the PRERELEASE area?

Or, do you have to wait, even for it to appear on the "Prerelease" area?

Anyone who actually knows ... THANK YOU.

Comment: BTW for November (2014) apple has, thank goodness, considerably improved the process.  it now seems to consistently move through the bizarre "prerelease" situation, in usually a couple minutes.  I would say if it takes more than a few minutes, you have some severe problem; scrap everything, start over, contact Apple, whatever.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816828/app-submission-binary-does-not-show-up-in-itunes-connect/25816865#25816865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some partial information ...

[image]

a build submitted at 1606 did appear on the "prerelease" area at 1651.....

[image]

**(So, 45 minutes later.)**

How did I make it happen?  Over on Xcode, I took the same archive, and clicked **validate**, let it process that, and then clicked **submit** again.  Half way through, the "first" one (from 45 minutes ago) did appear as shown here on the "Prerelease" section. I then just clicked to cancel that second upload (I guess it would have been harmless anyway.)  Coincidence? I don't know, but it worked.

So now - it's stuck in "prerelease" section!  :O

Comment: It appears that the build sits in this "processing" state for an indefinite time. As soon as you upload a new build, any existing builds are marked InActive and cannot be used. I now have 4 builds waiting to be processed. Apple have really messed up the whole process.

Comment: Hi Ferdil - quite right.  We eventually got through to a senior Apple tech at the iTunes desk.  They explained that SOMETIMES the problem is you have **some little piece of information missing, from the Metadata**.  (But there's no system to determine "what is missing".)  So, perhaps absolutely make sure you have all the stupid stuff such as at least one image for the various sizes, etc.  I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: In our case after putting in every possible piece of metadata, it was still stuck!  :)  But then I uploaded again with a new build # and it DID work.  In that final case, it was in "processing" for about 20 minutes, and then appeared OK, at last (after one week of fooling around) on the main page, and I submitted it.  How ridiculous, Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and now I have solved.

The reason for that is that your build is missing something that apple servers is unable to determine.

to solve this, make sure you have included all possible settings needed for your app submission, and make sure you have added at least one of the launch images for every possible resolution, that was my case, I added an launch image for every device and did works.

so, carefully check if you project is missing one of those settings or an image, and try.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have an App that Waiting for Review, the New App that you create and you upload... it will not Appear on +Build until the first App " Approved or Rejected"